# MySQL query returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I search on stack about this issue and found nothing. It's probably a syntax problem, but I don't figure it out.

```
//Include necessary files
include_once("inc/mysql.inc.php");
include_once("inc/security.inc.php");

//SECURITY: Check input before adding them into the table.
$u = security_checkinput($u);

//Connect to the MySQL database.
mysql_dbconnection();
//Go get users id corresponding to the search
$u = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users
            WHERE name LIKE \"%$u%\" OR active LIKE \"%$u%\" 
            ORDER BY name ASC") or die("There is a server error : " . mysql_error());
$u = mysql_fetch_row($u);
//Close database connection
mysql_dbclose();

//Return the array.
return $u;
```

I tried a mysql_num_rows on $u after the query and it returns me 0. Unfortunately, there is something in the users table and the name columns.

Any help?
Thanks a lot !!

EDIT: The problem is from the security_check function. I want to avoid as much as possible sql injection so I made this:

```
    function security_checkinput ($s)
{
    $s = stripslashes($s);
    if (!is_numeric($s))
        $s = "'".addslashes($s)."'";
    return $s;  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing your SQL statement, and running it directly against the database?

Comment: please see how [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator works..

Comment: `$u = security_checkinput($u);` -- what does `$u` contain? I am pretty sure it does not contain what you expect it to contain.

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1 :** You are assigning query to $u and using same variable in LIKE statement.

**Point 2 :**
You are writing ***[LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)*** statement incorrectly. It should be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users
            WHERE name LIKE '%$u%' OR active LIKE '%$u%' 
            ORDER BY name ASC") or die("There is a server error : " . mysql_error());
```

### OR

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users
            WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ,' , active) LIKE '%$u%' 
            ORDER BY name ASC") or die("There is a server error : " . mysql_error());
```

I would prefer CONCAT as you don't need to write n number of OR statements if there are many variables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you echo your query first and try to run it directly in database?

Anyways, use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) clause correctly..

```
$u = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users
            WHERE name LIKE '%$u%' OR active LIKE '%$u%' 
            ORDER BY name ASC") or die("There is a server error : " . mysql_error());
```

You don't need to use '/' here and phpvariable will be processed itself here. Try this

Comment: You're right my bad... I four that the problem was on my security_check function. I posted it into the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the sole cause of your problem, but this

```
WHERE name LIKE \"%$u%\" OR active LIKE \"%$u%\"
```

should be

```
WHERE name LIKE '%$u%' OR active LIKE '%$u%'
```

Have you tried running this query directly against your database?  What does it return there?

Comment: Actually it depends on the SQL mode in which MySQL is running. Normally MySQL will happily accept double quoted strings -- BUT -- if [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is on then _double quotes act as the backticks -- those that are used to enclose column names_.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very good point.  I think the issue here is probably related to what's in $u -- which hasn't been provided to us just yet.

Answer (score 0):

What is $u? Your query is fine, looks like you do not have any rows which match.

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81a7f/3)

Comment: $u is php variable, as defined above the query... :P

Comment: That's not helpful. :D String, int

Answer (score 0):

Your security function looks to be the problem.
Whenever $u is the word test, for example, it will return 'test'
which already is in your SQL statement.

Remove it out of your security function, and you'll be fine.
I do recommend however to change strip slashes and add slashes to something more decent, like mysql_real_escape_string

Example of the fix, based on old code:

```
function security_checkinput ($s)
{
    $s = stripslashes($s);
    if (!is_numeric($s))
        $s = addslashes($s);
    return $s;  
}
```

Example of mysql_real_escape_string usage *(you should really use this one instead)*:

```
function security_checkinput ($s){
$s = mysql_real_escape_string($s);
return $s;  
}
```

Make sure you also apply Nishu Tayal's solutiuon. The slashes don't belong there.